# Como insertar datos en mysql directamente en mayusculas?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Trato de guardar datos en agregados por los usuarios en una pagina web pero que a la hora de insertarlos se cambien todas las letras a mayusculas o bien a la hora de seleccionarlos los muestre todos en mayusculas lo segundo lo intento de esta forma (en la tabla tengo datos numericos y fechas)`SELECT UPPER(*) FROM` alumno``

Comment: consulta SQL: Documentación


SELECT UPPER(*) FROM alumno LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '*) FROM alumno LIMIT 0, 25' en la linea 1

Comment: INSERT INTO `sample_table`(`name`) values(UPPER('new text')) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240337/storing-data-into-mysql-in-uppercase